# ¿las medallas tienen alguna utilidad?, ¿todas las preguntas con premio de reputación aparecen como destacadas?

Tags: soporte, recompensas, medallas, privilegios

1. Quería saber si al ganar las medallas desbloqueas nuevas posibilidades como pasa con la reputación.
2. También me di cuenta que en destacados aparecen 3 preguntas con premio de reputación me gustaría saber si estas son todas las que hay actualmente con premio de reputación.

No encontré esta información en la guía, ni en Google, tampoco han hecho estas preguntas en el mismo sitio y la verdad me interesa.

Espero que puedan incluir estos datos en la guía en el futuro.

Comment: Las medallas se usan a menudo como criterio para los concursos internos ("si ganas la medalla xyz ganas un premio"), pero aparte de eso, son más para animar a los usuarios con un sistema de ludificación/gamificación... y quedan bonitas al lado del nombre :P

Comment: Y respondiendo a tu segunda pregunta: sí, esas son las únicas preguntas que hay de momento con una recompensa disponible. No hay tantas como en el sitio en inglés, pero normalmente siempre hay al menos una.

Comment: Gracias me fue útil tu respuesta

Comment: Pero voy a ver si encuentro alguna referencia oficial. No vaya a ser que te diga que no cuando es que sí.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tengo entendido y lo he visto en [so] y [meta.se] que, los que tienen medalla de oro en una etiqueta [pueden cerrarlas con un solo voto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/384394), pero no estoy seguro que tengamos eso aquí

Comment: @KacosPro De hecho, tienes toda la razón. Y sí tenemos eso aquí, ves como se me olvidaba un caso. Estaba pensando sólo en las medallas que aparecen en [esta lista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Comment: Además de lo que ya te mencionaron anteriormente, considero que las medallas son el reconocimiento a la labor que has realizado dentro del sitio, ediciones, respuestas, revisiones etc.

Comment: Sugiero dividir la pregunta en dos, pues son dos cosas totalmente distintas :)

Comment: @KacosPro efectivamente quienes tienen medalla de oro en una etiqueta pueden cerrar cualquier pregunta, pero únicamente si el motivo de cierre es porque se considera que la pregunta es **duplicada**, por otros motivos no se cierra la pregunta de forma inmediata aunque tengas medalla de oro. Me di cuenta de eso cuando obtuve una medalla de oro en la etiqueta `php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el [apartado sobre medallas en la ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) aparecen las medallas por grupos.

Entre los grupos hay uno llamado: **Medallas por etiquetas**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando obtienes una **medalla de oro de etiqueta** adquieres una nueva posibilidad: **cerrar de manera autónoma una pregunta al marcarla como duplicada e igualmente reabrirla**.

OJO: la pregunta no se cierra automáticamente por otros motivos, sólo si la marcas como duplicada.

Por ejemplo, esto es lo que dice en el caso de una medalla de etiqueta nivel oro para la etiqueta PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta donde sé, es el único caso en el que se desbloquean privilegios al adquirir medallas.

---

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta la respuesta es sí. Cuando se asigna recompensa a una pregunta aparece de inmediato en ese apartado y cuando se otorga la recompensa la pregunta ya no sigue apareciendo allí aunque le falten días para terminar el plazo.

Si la pregunta está marcada como solucionada o no es intrascendente para que aparezca en el apartado destacados, la condición es que tenga una recompensa abierta y que ésta no haya sido otorgada.